# How to combine multiple images together with specified proportions in python

Tags: python, image, rendering

How would one go about creating a montage of different images, with their relative sizes proportional to some given quantity?

For instance if I have:

```
img1=image1.png
img2=image2.png
img3=image3.png

render(file=img1,size=300px x 300px,file=img2,size=100px x 100px,file=img1,size=500px x 500px)
```

which would render as an image including all of the images 1-3 with relative sizes.

Any help achieving this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please strip the chemistry terms and replace them with common programming/Python language. Preferably with sample input and desired output. Extra code snippets that show your efforts is further appreciated.

Comment: @woozyking, hope that helps.